# Xamarin Android ConnectFailure (Connection Refused) - Has Internet permissions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that talks to an API hosted on Azure. Quick summary:

- UWP build works fine (no connection issues at all)
- Android build has INTERNET permission set

  - I don't get a permission notification though when running the app
- Android build is running on a *real device*, **not** an emulator
- I'm using RestSharp to build and send the HTTP requests (v106.5.4)

The Android build gives a "ConnectFailure (Connection Refused)" error when attempting to send an HTTP request to the hosted API.

I don't know what to try next, as I've never encountered such an issue.

Any advice and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT**
I can connect to the API via the browser on the device.

Comment: can you connect to the API using the browser on the device?

Comment: Hi @Jason yeah. I setup a test API method to return a simple message. I can connect to the API via the browser on the device.

Comment: check your server logs, or break out a tool like Wireshark to compare the requests between your clients

Comment: API level of your Android Device and your current target version

Comment: @G.hakim Device is 23, target is 27. I've not had an issue making HTTP requests with other apps, just this one. Could it be RestSharp? As this is the first time using it with Xamarin and the first time I've experienced this issue.

Comment: It could be restsharp i suggest you post the your code, And just want you to check if you have [runtime permissions](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-m/RuntimePermissions/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I presumed, after posting the question, RestSharp does not seem to play well with Android.

**The Fix**

Instead of RestSharp, you can use the `HttpClient` class from the `System.Net.Http` namespace. Here is further info, including examples: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Http.HttpClient?view=netframework-4.7.2). In some ways, it actually seems a little easier and simpler to use compared to RestSharp.

**Quick Tip**: Don't forget to set the base URI.